# How Do I Track Down a Phantom Endpoint in .NET 4.6

Tags: .net, visual-studio

So started up a new .NET project and immediately removed the Example endpoint controller that gets auto generated with the project. I built some new controllers, installed swagger and noticed that the removed Example endpoint was still alive and kicking despite me deleting it. I looked in the folder to see if the file was still around but it was gone. I closed down Visual Studio and rebuilt. No change. I cleaned the solution. No dice.

I used a different editor to search for any trace of the word "Example" in all the text files (there were none).

I removed the project and added it back in.

I renamed the project.

I opened the project in a different version of Visual Studio.

I have no idea how to hunt down this phantom controller.

Any advice?

Comment: Look at your project properties on the Build tab. Check the XML documentation file which might already exist in your /bin or /App_Data folder

Comment: App_Data folder is empty. The build XML file is almost completely empty except for the project name. No mention of the example controller anywhere.